# flex won't recognize my regular expressions definitions

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

i have a problem with writing definitions in flex in the L file. For some reason, flex doesn't recognize the name i give to the regular expression for example

```
LETTER [A-Za-z]
DIGIT[0-9]
SPACE  (" ") +
ID     {LETTER} ({LETTER} | {DIGIT})* (("."| "#"|"$" | "_")? ({LETTER} | {DIGIT})+)?
NUM    ({DIGIT} + | {DIGIT}+ "." {DIGIT} *)(((E |e) (+|-)? {DIGIT} +))?
%%
{LETTER}  {printf("letter");}
%%
```

but it does't execute the rule unless i write it this way:

```
[A-Za-z] {printf("letter");}
```

can any one tell me why is this happening ? thank you

Comment: I tried it with flex 2.5.38 and it works.

Comment: thanks maybe the problem was that i was using old flex package

Answer (score 0):

There are several faults in this flex program, but none of them are the one you are asking about. Perhaps you are getting confused between the cause and symptom of the faults you are seeing.

I can confirm that what you are asking about works in all versions of flex:

```
LETTER [A-Za-z]
%%
{LETTER}  {printf("letter");}
%%
```

The faults are in the other regular expressions, which are not referenced in your example. If you do reference them, then it does generate faults which you might be inadvertently contributing to the letter pattern. Let's examine why that might be so, by putting actions for the other patterns:

```
LETTER [A-Za-z]
DIGIT[0-9]
SPACE  (" ") +
ID     {LETTER} ({LETTER} | {DIGIT})* (("."| "#"|"$" | "_")? ({LETTER} | {DIGIT})+)?
NUM    ({DIGIT} + | {DIGIT}+ "." {DIGIT} *)(((E |e) (+|-)? {DIGIT} +))?
%%
{LETTER}    {printf("letter");}
{SPACE} {printf("space");}
{ID}    {printf("id");}
{NUM}   {printf("num");}
%%
```

We get this response from flex:

```
SO.l:8: unrecognized rule
SO.l:9: unrecognized rule
SO.l:10: unrecognized rule
```

This is because there are faults in the regular expressions. You have made the mistake of putting whitespace in them. In most code whitespace is ignored, but a common mistake made by beginners in flex (and other tools that use regular expressions) is to add spacing to improve readability. This is not a good idea, because it can often result in specifying that the whitespace should occur in the pattern! It therefore assumes that your specification requires two spaces in the `{space}` pattern, and that space occur in an `{ID}` and a `{NUM}`.

Removing the spaces we end up with this:

```
LETTER  [A-Za-z]
DIGIT   [0-9]
SPACE  (" ")+
ID     {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*(("."|"#"|"$"|"_")?({LETTER}|{DIGIT})+)?
NUM    ({DIGIT}+|{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}*)(((E|e)(+|-)?{DIGIT}+))?
%%
{LETTER}    {printf("letter");}
{SPACE} {printf("space");}
{ID}    {printf("id");}
{NUM}   {printf("num");}
%%
```

That resolves most of the faults, leaving one more:

```
SO.l:11: unrecognized rule
```

This is caused by a fault in the NUM pattern. The `+` symbol has been used in the pattern to show where a sign can be used in a number. However, the plus sign is used in regular expressions to mean a repetition of one or more. The `+` needs to be put in quotes:

```
LETTER  [A-Za-z]
DIGIT   [0-9]
SPACE  (" ")+
ID     {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*(("."|"#"|"$"|"_")?({LETTER}|{DIGIT})+)?
NUM    ({DIGIT}+|{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}*)(((E|e)("+"|"-")?{DIGIT}+))?
%%
{LETTER}    {printf("letter");}
{SPACE} {printf("space");}
{ID}    {printf("id");}
{NUM}   {printf("num");}
%%
```

This code now builds, and even compiles with gcc. We can run the code on some examples:

```
a123
id
123
num
123.456
num
123.456e-78
num

space
a
letter
aa
id
```

You should also note, that having a `{LETTER}` rule and a `{ID}` rule can be a problem. A single letter gets matched to a `LETTER`, but more than one character is matched to an 'ID'. This is because flex tries to achieve the longest match. If you tried to change the matching order to give preference to an ID, you would get an error from flex diagnosing this condition:

```
LETTER  [A-Za-z]
DIGIT   [0-9]
SPACE  (" ")+
ID     {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*(("."|"#"|"$"|"_")?({LETTER}|{DIGIT})+)?
NUM    ({DIGIT}+|{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}*)(((E|e)("+"|"-")?{DIGIT}+))?
%%
{SPACE} {printf("space");}
{ID}    {printf("id");}
{NUM}   {printf("num");}
{LETTER}    {printf("letter");}
%%
```

Which gives:

```
SO.l:10: warning, rule cannot be matched
```

This is another common source of errors for beginner, having a string which matches more than one pattern.

Comment: Originally this question was flagged because the fault was not reproducible. However that [fault aged away and cannot be re-flagged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away). On closer examination the question contained a significant number of beginner faults that could be solved and an answer provided.